# VSCode: Increase opacity of linter warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, theming, material-design

I resently switched to Visual Studio Code as my editor. I installed my favorite theme ["Material Theme Palenight High Contrast"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme). I'm in love with it. There is just on problem, that really hinders me when coding on my laptop.

The squiggly lines of the linting error are super dark, because they have opacity.

[image]

As you can see here, one can barely see the error below `item`. Is there a way to change the opacity of linting errors?

**EDIT:** I tried setting `workbench.colorCustomizations` but that caused my theme to disappear.

**Edit 2:** I tried setting the theme specific settings like this:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[Material Theme Ocean High Contrast]": {
    "editorError.foreground": "#ff0000"
  }
},
```

but it didn't work. The color of the squiggly stayed the same.

Comment: The error squiggly was originally red and you tried to set it to red so no difference.  Try a different color and/or the editorError.bordet color customization.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions on [the theme page you linked](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme#color-scheme-override) say to use `editor.colorCustomizations`, not `workbench.colorCustomizations`. Have you tried that?

There's also a bit above the link I gave that talks about setting the accent color. They don't define what "accent color" means, so I'm not sure if that color is the thing you're trying to change, but you might try it.

Comment: There is no such thing as `editor.colorCustomizations` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a fix. Go to the place where your extensions are installed:

```
/Users/user-name/.vscode/extensions/extension-name/themes/theme-name.json
```

In that file find the values for `editorError.foreground` and `editorWarning.foreground`. Here you can overwrite their values and it will work.

I'm just asking myself, whether this should be an issue for the VSCode repository? Since setting the settings in the user settings should overwrite this. One shouldn't have to change this `.json` file. Especially since this will change back again, if you re-install the theme.

**Dummy Edit ‍♂️:**

Damn, I accidently wrote *Oceaning* insteand of *Palenight*. The color customizations work... My bad. No need to do this hacky trick I described above.